# Why is $.get() not working properly

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm trying to retrieve a line of code from a php file. My code is as follows:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    alert("1");
    $.get('http://myurl.com/toolbox/myPHP.php?store_id=4649b4a8a802c3&couponShow=checkout', function(data) {
        alert(data);
        alert("2");
    });
});   

window.onload = function() {
    if (window.jQuery) {
        // jQuery is loaded
        alert("Yeah!");
    } else {
        // jQuery is not loaded
        alert("Doesn't Work");
    }
}
```

`"1"` and `"Yeah!"` are alerted properly, so jQuery is loading, but I can't get inside the get function. Visiting the url inside returns exactly what's expected. Is there something wrong with what I'm doing here? What steps could I take to find the problem?

Comment: Are you trying to fetch content cross-domain? Check the dev tools console for errors.

Comment: Or from harddisk. Same problem

Comment: Yes, and cross domain is allowed on the server.

Comment: Replace $.get shortcut with $.ajax request and catch errors.

Comment: You should always _catch_ the errors of your request might _throw_ `$.get().fail(function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) { /* some error handling*/ })`.

Comment: Like PeterKA said, check the developer tools (F12) for console errors. You can view the entire ajax request through the developer tools and it will show you why it failed, what the response was if it went through (http status code is helpful) and more.

Comment: Thanks everyone, I'm not sure what the issue was, but it started working seemingly all of a sudden.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `.fail()` at the end of your request to determine if its an error regarding the php file.

Use the `data` callback to receive the details of the failed request

**This will work:**

```
$.get("http://api.postcodes.io/postcodes?q=da117ne", function (data) {
  alert("it worked: " + data.status);
}).fail(function (data) {
  alert(data.statusText);
});
```

**This will not, but will give a response of the error**

```
$.get("dedededhttp://api.postcodes.io/postcodes?q=da117ne", function (data) {
  alert("it worked: " + data.status);
}).fail(function (data) {
  alert(data.statusText);
});
```

Here is an example on jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/rx6ws7hw/

Comment: An example would make this a much better answer. As it is, this is pretty much just a comment or suggestion.

Comment: Thanks @JonathanKuhn I have provided the code and a jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    alert("1");
    $.get('http://myurl.com/toolbox/myPHP.php?store_id=4649b4a8a802c3&couponShow=checkout')
     .done( function() {
        alert("2");
    }).fail(function(){
        alert("3") ;
    });
});
```

[See Jquery $.Get](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/)

Comment: Thanks, I'm not sure what the issue was, but it started working seemingly all of a sudden.

Answer (score 0):

I tried a copy/paste slightly modified version like this on the current page (it worked):

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $.get('http://stackoverflow.com', function(data) {
        window.console.log(data);
    });
});
```

If you would like to try it out you can do the same.

On this page, in Chrome, press Command+Option+I (Menu -> More Tools -> Developer Tools). Click the console tab at the top of this new "developer pane" that appears. Paste the above code into the console and press enter.

However, if I change it slightly,

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $.get('http://google.com', function(data) {
        window.console.log(data);
    });
});
```

I get this (without adding .fail for debugging):

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://google.com/?_=1419962724028. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://stackoverflow.com' is therefore not allowed access.
```

I'm not super familiar with fetching content via cross-domain, but maybe employing this little test on your own server will lead you in the right direction.

I think we need more information to more fully diagnose the problem though.

I apologize if you already knew all of this :) I know it's simple, but it's the first place I would start.